# How get Rotation / Orientation of object from mesh?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, mesh, quaternions

I try to know the rotation / orientation of an object with his meshes. Let me explain, I import some OBJ in Unity. This is the same parts but in different place (exported from the same exporter).
For the position, this is not a big deal, but for rotation, it's not the same problem.

Example with these 2 nuts. It's the same object but different rotation :

[image]

[image]

In my Unity transform all values are position(0,0,0), rotation(0,0,0), scale (1,1,1).
So I tried this code to get rotation from the normal of the same object :

```c#
Vector3 normalOne = ObjectOne.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.normals[0];
Vector3 normalTwo = ObjectTwo.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.normals[0];

Quaternion q = Quaternion.FromToRotation(normalOne, normalTwo);
ObjectOne.transform.rotation = q * ObjectOne.transform.rotation;
```

But it's not working. This is the result of the operation:
[image]

Can someone have an idea of how to do that ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `But it's not working.` what does it mean exactly? Shouldn't it be the other way raound: `ObjectOne.transform.rotation = ObjectOne.transform.rotation * q;`? order matters when rotating

Comment: did you create this model? if yes, what software did u use? Open that software and change rotation...so u dont need to do it in Unity by coding.

Comment: @derHugo : Thank you for this answer. I know this is not commutative so I tried the other way round but it's not working. I edited my post to add the result of the operation described.

Comment: @Perazim : No I did'nt created this model. I tried to create a automatic workflow in Unity to handle multiple setup with same parts to avoid multiple loading of pretty similar models. I can't change rotation and position before export ! ;)

Comment: How do you know the `sharedMesh.normals[0]` is the "same" one for both models? The rotation to me looks like quite straight forward `90°` .. wouldn't it be easier to simply add a wrapper GameObject as parent and rotate the child accordingly?

Comment: @derHugo : I'm not very sure, but I guess it. I did a check by creating the first triangle of each object and it's seem to be the same. So I guess only vertices position are different for both models. Pretty easy to modify GameObject in Unity with the visual editor but, I want to do it by script automatically for all parts and it will not be always 90° ! ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, a single vector angle difference will not give you a full rotation - it only gives a part of the rotation, along the axis given by the crossproduct of the two normals. To get a full rotation, you'll need to match the vertices of the two models (or assume they're represented/exported in the same order), and then extract a transformation matrix from the corresponding points (a bit of maths required - there are a few ways of doing it, but most require something like an SVD or polar decomposition to get the final result). If you think this is the right way, I can try to elaborate.